# include Class Name in JSON Generic Property Serialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I've created the following class to represent any server response for REST API requests:

```
[DataContract]
public class ServerResponse<T>
{
    [DataMember(Name = "error")]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "data")]
    public T Data { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "success")]
    public bool Success { get; set; } 
}
```

When using it with a simple class like this one

```
[DataContract(Name = "category")]
public class Category
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I get the following response

```
{
  "error": "",
  "data": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Top"
   },
  "success": true
}
```

I want to include the generic type class name in the serializaion. wanted outcome:

```
{
  "error": "",
  "data": {
      "category": {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Top"
      }
   },
  "success": true
}
```

How can I do that?
(I've seen answers in similar posts but non of them apply to a generic scenario like this one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting my workaround if it will help anybody

I've created a custom Json converter

```
public class GenericTypeJsonSerializer : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Parse data object
        var dataObject = JToken.FromObject(value);

        // Extract generic type class serialization name
        var className = ExtractClassName(value);

        // Create wrapper object that includes generic class name
        JObject wrapperObject = new JObject();
        wrapperObject.Add(className, dataObject);

        // write object
        wrapperObject.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public string ExtractClassName(object value)
    {
        // extract data contract attribute
        var dataContractAttribute = value.GetType()
            .GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DataContractAttribute)) as DataContractAttribute;
        // return name declared in attribute
        if (dataContractAttribute?.Name != null)
            return dataContractAttribute.Name;

        // return default class name
        return value.GetType().Name;
    }
}
```

And I've decorated the generic `Data` property with a `JsonConverter` attribute

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(GenericTypeJsonSerializer))]
    [DataMember(Name = "data")]
    public T Data { get; set; }
```

c'est tout!